# Bad install of bisigi themes

Tags: software-installation

```
E: Type' ://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu' is not known on line 2 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bisigi-ppa-maverick.list 
E:Unable to lock the list directory
```

This is blocking me from entering the Synaptic Package Manager! What is going on? 
Help!

Comment: Remove the ppa and if you want re add it again but make sure you add it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a bad sources list configuration.

Using the following command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

allows you to edit the sources list file.  Find the line that points to the bisigi PPA and edit it so that it looks exactly as below:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu natty main
```

Save the file and exit.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the PPA by going to Software Sources and removing it. Then to add it back, just do the following in Terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bisigi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bisigi-themes
```

Comment: I was able to remove the ppa, but the mess is still there, with the same error messages as before. How can I remove the bisigi themes and what I downloaded in the terminal? Will that help to resolved this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the repositories from

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and then remove

```
bisigi-ppa-oneiric.list
bisigi-ppa-oneiric.list.save
```